# NOSQL document relation

Tags: pouchdb, nosql

i try to understand how pouchdb work, i am new with nosql. Every tutorial on internet seems too basic so i can't really understand .

I have two JSON document . One of them is to keep the static record, value of this document will be inserted into every new document created .

In the traditional sql, we can easily create 2 table, select value from the static table then insert it together with new record. But it is too different with nosql. Please guide me how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try relational-pouch:  https://github.com/nolanlawson/relational-pouch